# Proper way to call a custom php function from another file

Tags: php, function

I would like to use custom functions that are all located in one file called functions.php that resides in the includes folder.

A custom function inside functions.php is below and it seems to be working when I remove function `nos_check () {}` and load up functions.php alone.

```
function nos_check() {
    require_once ('config.php');
    mysql_connect($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Unable to select database");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT number_of_sites FROM sites WHERE user = '$currentUsername' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    // Assign how many sites the user has into a variable
    $how_many = $row['number_of_sites'];
    mysql_close();
        if ($how_many == 0) {
            echo 'You have no sites yet';
        } else {
            echo 'You have more than one site';
            }
    }
```

The file account.php is what's going to call that function:

```
include "includes/functions.php";
nos_check();
```

I think I am probably calling the function incorrectly or perhaps I am including the functions file wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

After hours of messing around and reading more about mysqli etc. I realized that the only problem I actually had was that the script had no idea what `$currentUsername` was because it was a [global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and functions are not including them automatically in php.

So the error could have been fixed easily by putting `global $currentUsername;` inside the function `nos_check()`

Below is a rewritten and hopefully better looking code as well:

```
function nos_check() {
    require 'config.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    global $currentUsername;
    $query = "SELECT number_of_sites FROM sites WHERE user = '$currentUsername' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);

    if ($row[0] == 0) {
        echo 'You have no sites yet';
        } else {
            echo 'You have more than one site';
            }
    }
```

Comment: There's a few 'best practice' that you could improve on... Use Mysqli, and have the require_once outside of the function.

Comment: Configure [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) so that you can see error messages for errors that happened.

Comment: mysql_ functions are DEPRECATED: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. You MUST update Your code to latest standarts, like PDO.

Comment: When I take the `require_once` outside of that function I get the following error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: I understand that I should use mysqli instead of mysql, but the problem lies elsewhere right now...